# Mysql create table with sums of nulls and not nulls

Tags: mysql, sql

**Scenario:** I am trying to create an output matrix where I have all the columns names (fields) of a source table in the first column, followed by the sum of all Null values of that original field column.

Ex:

```
Original Table:
Id1     Code     Range
aa       33       null
ab       12       001
ac       53       001
ad       null     null
null     36       002
```

**Wanted output:**

```
Fields    #ofnull   #ofnonnull
Id1          1          4
Code         1          4
Range        2          3
```

For this I have a code that retrieves the names and positions of all the columns in the original matrix, and a snippet which counts my nulls/nonnulls.

**Issue:** I have no idea how to string those together and get this output with a single query. I tried searching around, but most answers were regarding just counting the nulls, not on the process on inputting a list of columns to the query.

**Question:** Is it possible to do this? or do I have to feed the query each column name manually?

**Code so far:**

```
select
    `ordinal_position`,
    `column_name`,
from `dev1`.`info`
where `table_schema` = 'dev1'
and `table_name` = 'data1'
order by `ordinal_position`;

select 
    count(1)
from `dev1`.`data1`
where Id1 is null;
-- where Id1 is not null;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach uses a series of unions:

```
SELECT
    'Id1' AS Fields, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Id1 IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS NoNull,
    COUNT(Id1) AS NoNonNull
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Code', COUNT(CASE WHEN Code IS NULL THEN 1 END), COUNT(Code)
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Range', COUNT(CASE WHEN `Range` IS NULL THEN 1 END), COUNT(`Range`)
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: too fast while I was typing the answer; +1; although your forgot to add `Fields` column. Added to it

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Another problem: `RANGE` appears to be a reserved MySQL keyword, so I had to escape it in backticks to get the query to work.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya another answer also here which is 7sec before this answer have not you noticed :)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen One question: what is the effect of selecting "Id1" as fields?

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin this answer is more efficient. It avoids the usage of unnecessary sub-select (Derived table) in this case.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, thank you,  group by was missing :)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen oh i see he may be missed to put group by :)

Comment: @DGMS89 To answer your question, it is just selecting a constant.  This is the actual string literal name of the field which you want to appear in the unpivoted output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Understood. Just one more thing: since I have around 60 columns in my original table, would it be possible to automate this without having the: SELECT 'column_name', COUNT(CASE WHEN `column_name` IS NULL THEN 1 END), COUNT(`column_name`) over and over again?

Comment: @DGMS89 You would probably have to write some dynamic SQL for that, which is basically writing code to generate actual MySQL code.  As you can probably guess, you'd have some kind of loop over all column names, generating the `COUNT` expressions for each column.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ok that's what I was expecting. Do you now any source where I can learn more about dynamic sql?

Comment: If you are not so SQL inclined, you could just as easily write a script in any tool (e.g. Excel, Java, etc.) which churns out the count expressions, using a list of column names.  To learn more about dynamic MySQL, just check the documentation and Stack Overflow.  Believe it or not, it doesn't come up often here.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT
    field,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN val IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS `#ofnull`,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN val IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS `#ofnotnull`
FROM
(
    SELECT 'Id1' AS field, Id1 AS val FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Code', Code FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Range', `Range` FROM yourTable
) a
GROUP BY field;
```